# Flask response loses unprintable characters in string

Tags: python, json, flask, serialization

I have a string variable in python which looks like this:

`'\x1d0103671286378126378127812\x1d1232321102I009B\x1d71012321271'`

when sending it in a json response, all `\x1d` characters are missing.

.. but printing it on the console works without a problem.

I also tried `json.dumps(array)` and `jsonify(array)` but the `\x1d` is always missing.

Is there a way to properly escape it in the json response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape `\` characters with another `\` character i.e.

```
str = '\\x1d0103671286378126378127812\\x1d1232321102I009B\\x1d71012321271'
```

or in general

```
str = '\x1d0103671286378126378127812\x1d1232321102I009B\x1d71012321271'
str = str.replace('\x1d', '\\x1d')
```

print(str) -> `\x1d0103671286378126378127812\x1d1232321102I009B\x1d71012321271`

You can then send that string as is

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a proper "javascript compatible escaped string" variant ..

Comment: I am confused by this response? What do you mean by "proper "javascript compatible escaped string""?

Comment: You can preform this action on the frontend in Javascript if this string is in javascript, and being sent to python backend. You use "str = str.replaceAll('\x1d', '\\x1d');" before sending. Is this what you mean?

Comment: sorry, maybe that was a little misleading .. I meant that, AFAIK a JSON value should be able to contain a hex 1d character, or at least the escaped variant "\x1d" on its own. It should not be necessary to escape the backslash again, because "\\x1d" will be decoded to a string "\x1d" and not the corresponding hex character itself.
`{'key':'val\x1due'}` should be correct but the answer above would generate `{'key':'val\\x1due'}` right?